# Stuck in Induction Inequality: $2^n>3n^2$

Tags: inequality, induction

I am doing an inequality induction question that looks like this:

Prove that $2^n>3n^2$ for $n\geq 8$

So I have done Step $1,2$ but I can't finish step $3$

Step $1$: RTP: $n=8$

LHS=$2^8=256$

RHS=$3(8)^2=192$

Therefore  true for $n=8$

Step $2$: Ass $n=k$

$2^k>3k^2$

Step 3: RTP: $n=k+1$

$2^{k+1}>3(k+1)^2$

LHS=$2^k \cdot 2$

$>2 \cdot (3k^2)$

$=6k^2$

New aim-RTP: $6k^2>3 \cdot (k+1)^2$

$6k^2>3k^2+6k+3$

I am stuck here, how do I continue beyond this step?

Comment: why are you writing the product as . instead of $\cdot$?

Comment: "\cdot" is the symbol that accomplishes this, BTW

Comment: You should take a look [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) to learn how to properly format math in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $6k^2\ge3(k+1)^2\iff 2k^2\ge(k+1)^2\iff 2k^2\ge k^2+2k+1\iff k^2\ge2k+1$.

Now use your assumption that $k\ge8$, so $k^2\ge 8k$.

Comment: is there a way to prove $k^2>2k+1$ without using the assumption?

Comment: @user117196 For $k = 0$ or $k = 1$, this is not true. Hence, you need some assumption on $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write your statement as

$$2^n - 3n^2 > 0.$$

That way, you can work with the both parts at once (as they are on the same side of the inequality).

So, your final step transforms to

$$6k^2 - 3k^2 -6k - 3 = 3k^2 -6k - 3 = 3 (k^2 - 2k - 1) > 3 (k^2 - 2k - 3) = 3(k-3)(k+1).$$

Since we have assumed that $k \ge 8$...

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you consider the real function $f(x) = 3x^2 -6x - 3$ ?

Comment: I doubt the OP is still stuck there after 18 months.

Comment: What do you mean by "OP"? Sorry, I'm not so familiar with English and this site.

Comment: On math.SE, "[Original Poster](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op)".