# Show that $2^n > n^2$ whenever n>4.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let $S(n)$ be the proposition "$2^n > n^2$"

Basis step: $S(5)$ is true, since $2^5 = 32$, $ 32 > 25 = 5^ 2$

Inductive step:

Induction hypothesis:

Assume $S(K)$ is true, $2^K > K^2$.

Then

$2^{K+1} = 2.2^K > K^2 + K^2$

I don't know how to proceed after this. How to complete this proof?

Comment: It's actually true for all $n\in\mathbb R$, $n>4$. You can show this by observing that the inequality is equivalent to $2^{1/2}>n^{1/n}$ and analyzing the function $f(x)=x^{1/x}$.

Comment: The induction step is $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n>2\cdot n^2=n^2+n^2>n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$ The last inequality follows from $n^2>3n=2n+n>2n+1$

Comment: If you really want to prove it for all real numbers $x>4$, I would suggest to take the logarthms and look at the function $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$

Comment: Related proofs by induction are [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643165/stuck-in-induction-inequality-2n3n2) and [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180201/prove-by-mathematical-induction-that-forall-n-in-mathbbn-3n-n3).  The first of these is noticeably stronger than what is required in the current Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have: $2^{K+1} > 2K^2 > K^2 + 2K+1 = (K+1)^2$

Comment: How did you reach `\(2K^2 > K^2 + 2K +1\)`? How did you get to that `2K+1` part?

Comment: @piepi You can show that when $K>4$, $K^2 > 4 K > 2K +1$.

Comment: So do I need to show `4K>2K+1` separately or is that implied because I don't think we have proved this relation yet?

Comment: $K^2 > 2K+1$ is quite clear because $K$ is a natural number $ \ge 3$. The case $K = 1,2$ can be checked easily.

Comment: @CHwC I don't follow.