# $\forall n \geq 5$ prove $2^n > n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I am trying to prove the title using induction and here is my attempt:

Base Case: n = 1 : $2>1$ which is True

I.H. : $2^k > k^2$ for some $k$

Inductive Step:

$2^{k+1} = 2^k 2$

$2^{k+1} > 2k^2$ by I.H.

But I am not quite sure what to do next.

Comment: How about proving $2k^2>(k+1)^2$?

Comment: Try proving that $n^2 < 2^n$ instead of what you have.  Sometimes reversing the inequality can make the inductive step seem more natural.

Comment: Note that your base case should be $n=5$.

Comment: Note that $2^4 \not> 4^2$, so your proof which starts with the base case $n=1$ had *better not work*! You picked the wrong base case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $2^n > n^2$ whenever n>4.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882584/show-that-2n-n2-whenever-n4)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Using $k \geq 5$,

$$\begin{align}
2k^2&=k^2+k^2 \\
&\geq k^2+5k\\
&> k^2+2k+k\\
&> k^2+2k+1.
\end{align}$$